# How do I offset the start time in GCP's Cloud Scheduler?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have a series of Cloud Scheduler jobs that all call the same service, but with different payloads. The requirement for these jobs is that the frequency of the jobs must match. Meaning that I want them all to run every five minutes, but they need not be at the same time. Every five minutes, the service gets a large spike in usage, and then dies down. I would like to offset the activation time of each job but maintain the frequency so as to smooth the usage curve of the service the job calls.

I know in crontab I could write `1/5 * * * *` which would mean it activates every five minutes, but offset by one minute. This cronjob would activate at the 1st, 6th, 11th, etc minutes. When I try to use this cron frequency in GCP's Cloud Scheduler, it does not accept it and says `"1/5" is not a valid value for minute (0-59).`

How do I offset the activation of my Cloud Scheduler jobs?

Comment: not sure I understand completely, but do you think something like this `1,6,11,16,21,26,31,36,41,46,51,56 * * * *` might work?

Comment: Another solution is to create PubSub message with Cloud Scheduler and to let PubSub deliver the messages to your services